# I can't use modifiers on more than one UI element in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my first day learning Jetpack Compose and I'm having trouble. I can't seem to add a modifier to more than one UI element. I have two text UI elements in the same function. I put a modifier in the first element and it works fine, but the second one doesn't work. It gives me an error that says "Unresolved reference: modifier".

Here are the imports

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme
```

Here is the rest of the file. The modifier in the second text UI element is red but the first one isn't. I added two separate modifiers as parameters in the function.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(textModifier1: Modifier = Modifier, textModifier2: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column (
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ){
        Text(
            text = "Hello Android!",
            modifier = textModifier1
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )

        Text(
            text = "Goodbye Android!"
            modifier = textModifier2
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Greeting()
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You forgot to put a comma after `text = "Goodbye Android!"`.

Comment: Thanks. I wish you could see me slap myself.